# (VSTO project)This version of visual studio is unable to open the following projects Vs2015

Tags: c#, asp.net

A few months ago my project of Microsoft outlook plugin was running fine but now I reopened it and I am getting this nasty error.

Can anyone give me some inputs regarding this error?

I would be really thankful. Here is the screenshot of the error prompt I get
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUqte.png)